# The proof of Hadamard' Lemma

Tags: differential-geometry

i'm currently studying a little differential geometry and I have some difficulties.
I actually  cannot understand the proof of the Hadamard's lemma that I've found in almost every course I've checked. 
Here's the lemma followed by the proof :

We take : $M$ a differentiable manifold with $dimM = n$ and $p \in M$ .

Let $(U,\varphi )$ , $\varphi = (x^1 , ... , x^n)$ , a chart s.t $\varphi (p) = 0$ . ( We define $C^{\infty}(p)$ to be the set of maps $ f : U \overset{{C^{\infty}}}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{R} $ where we identify the maps being equal on somme neighbourhood of $ p $  contained in $ U $ ) .

$\forall g \in C^{\infty}(p)$ , $ \exists \chi_{1} ... \chi_{n} \in C^{\infty}(p) $ s.t $$ g = g(p) + \sum_{i=1}^{n} x^{i} \chi_{i} $$ .

Now with the proof :

We apply the Taylor's formula with integral rest :
\begin{align}
 g \circ \varphi^{-1} (x^1 , ... , x^n) - g \circ \varphi^{-1} (0) = \int_0^{1} \frac{d}{dt}[g \circ \varphi^{-1} (tx^1 , ... , tx^n)]dt\\
= \sum_{i=1}^{n} x^{i} \int_0^{1}  \frac{\partial g \circ \varphi^{-1}}{\partial x{i}} (tx) dt \tag{1} 
\end{align}

By putting $$ \chi_{i} \circ \varphi^{-1} (x) = \int_0^{1}  \frac{\partial g \circ \varphi^{-1}}{\partial x{i}} (tx) dt $$ and composing with $ \varphi $ in both sides we obtain the desired formula.
(end of the proof)

I specify you where I have the problem : First I searched the Taylor's formula with integral rest but I can not understand how it was used in the proof. Secondly I do not understand the calculation made by moving from one line to another in $ (1) $ .

Can someone please help me ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps involving Taylor is a bit of overkill: If $0\in \Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, for some $\Omega$ open, and $f\colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ then we can define for each direction $v\in B_\varepsilon(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, for some $\varepsilon$ small enough, the function $f_v\colon [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f_v(t)=f(tv)$. Then the fundamental theorem of calculus says
$$
f(v)-f(0)=f_v(1) -f_v(0) = \int_0^1 f_v'(s) ds =\int_0^1 \nabla f(sv)\cdot v ds.
$$
Now just write $f=g \circ \varphi^{-1}$ and $v=x$ so that the above formula becomes
$$
g \circ \varphi^{-1}(x) - g\circ \varphi^{-1}(0) = \int_0 ^1 \nabla( g \circ \varphi^{-1}(sx)) \cdot xds.
$$
This is what you want.