# Does this define a smooth map?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am trying to justify a sentence in Milnor's H-cobordism book.  I feel like my explanation is too simple.  It occurs on page 64.

In the book, it asserts that given a smooth homotopy $h_t: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ (between a map $h$ and the identity on $\mathbb{R}^n$), we can express it in the form
$$h_t(x) = x_1h^1(t,x) + \ldots + x_nh^n(t,x), \hspace{2cm} x = (x_1,\ldots, x_n)$$
where $h^i(t,x)$ is a smooth function of $t$ and $x$, for $i = 1,\ldots, n$ and $h^i(t,0) = \frac{\partial h_t}{\partial x_i} (0)$.

I feel like my justification is too naive/elementary and as a result, the functions I've defined aren't smooth:

Note that
\begin{align*}
h_t(x) =&\, \int_0^1 \frac{d h_t(sx_1, \ldots, sx_n)}{ds} ds\\
=& \, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\cdot\underbrace{\left[\int_0^1 \frac{\partial h_t}{\partial x_i} (sx_1, \ldots, sx_n)\right]}_{:= h^i(t,x)}
\end{align*}

I would gladly appreciate any feedback/nudges in the right direction.

Comment: See [Hadamard's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_lemma), and [The proof of Hadamard' Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205270/the-proof-of-hadamard-lemma).

Comment: @user539887 ok!  I forgot to mention that we assume that the map $h$ has the added property that $h(0)=0$.  And now I see that it matches the lemma you gave.  I'm still not quite sure how to show it is smooth in $t$, though.

Comment: It appears that by taking the gradient at most one differentiation in $x$ is lost (of course, as you consider homotopy, you have also dependence on $t$; but that is only a technicality, I think).  If you understand by "smooth" $C^{\infty}$, everything seems O.K.